# Prove or disprove: $\forall p\in[0,1),\,\int_0^1 x\oplus p\,dx=\frac12$, where $\oplus$ is the bitwise XOR operation.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For $x\in[0,1)$, let $(x_k)\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N^*}$ be its bits coefficients, i.e.
$$x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k2^{-k}.$$

I want to prove (or disprove) that

$$\forall p\in[0,1),\,\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(x_k\oplus p_k\right)2^{-k}\,dx=\frac12,$$

where $\oplus$ is the XOR operation, i.e.

$$x_k\oplus p_k=
\begin{cases}
1\quad\text{if $x_k\neq p_k$}\\
0\quad\text{if $x_k=p_k$}
\end{cases}=(x_k+p_k) \mod2.$$

The idea is very simple, when we do the XOR with $p$ for all numbers in $[0,1]$, the results are kind of uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, thus we'll finally have $\frac12$.

The problem here is how to prove this observation using formal mathematical language, noticing that the function $f:x\mapsto x\oplus p$ is very strange, not continue, not Riemann integrable (but measurable and bounded).

Comment: $0.01111\dots_2 = 0.1_2$, so there are $x$s in $[0,1)$ with two binary expansions.  You don't say whether you use zero, one or both representations and, if one, which one.

Comment: @EricTowers the set of $x$ with more than one binary representation is countable and therefore measure zero, so you can ignore the issue without changing the answer

Comment: @Adam : Since the most direct answer involves $- \oplus p$ being a permutation, it's much easier if this is resolved.

Comment: @EricTowers you can solve it using whichever choice of convention makes it easiest, and then appeal to measure theory to say that the answer is the same no matter what convention you chose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the King property $\int_0^1f(x)dx=\tfrac12\int_0^1(f(x)+f(1-x))dx$. Since$$(x\oplus p)+((1-x)\oplus p)=\sum_k2^{-k}=1$$(with countably many exceptions, namely the dyadic fraction values of $x$), the original integral is $\tfrac12\int_0^1dx=\tfrac12$.

Comment: Very nice indeed!  Is this a well known trick of the trade or did you just come up with it?

Comment: @Ruy The King property $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$ is used extensively.

Comment: I wonder if the king property could be applied to the ternary analogue of this problem.

Comment: @Mars Well, something similar, anyway. It depends on how you define $\oplus$ on ternary digits. You just need $\sum_{i=0}^2j\oplus k$ to have the same value for all $k\in\{0,\,1,\,2\}$.

Comment: assume $a\oplus b=1$ if they are equal, and zero otherwise. Then the integral should be $1/3$. Instead of $f(x)+f(1-x)$ what would you use?

Comment: @Mars I think you need something a bit more sophisticated, such as a uniform Dirichlet distribution on $x,\,y,\,z\ge0,\,x+y+z=1$. Note that $(x\oplus p)+\cdots$ is almost always $\sum_{k\ge1}2/3^k=1$.

Comment: @J.G. thanks, that helped, I'll look into Dirichlet distribution since I don't think I've ever heard of it.

Comment: @J.G. I figured a way to make things work in the n-ary case similar to the binary case. Consider the map $g(x)$ which increase the value of each digit by one mod n, in the expansion of x. If we're in binary then $g(x)=1-x$, otherwise $g$ is not continuous however we can show $g(x)$ is measure preserving and $1=\int \Sigma_{k=0}^{k=n-1} (g^k(x)\oplus p)dx=n\int x\oplus p$ dx.

Answer (score 0):

You want to break your interval up into $2^k$ intervals, and put upper and lower bounds on each interval. Then take limit as k goes to infinity, using bounded convergence theorem, bounded by the constant function 1. For instance when you break it into one interval, the upper bound is 1 and lower bound is 0. When you break it up into two intervals, the upper bound is 1/2(1+1/4) and lower bound is 1/2(0+1/2). When you break it into 4 intervals the upper bound is 1/4(1+1/2+1/2+1/4) and the lower bound is 1/4(3/4+1/2+1/4)=6/16 and so on. I will leave it to you to workout the details.